# Using single dbcontext for unit of work in service layer

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I trying to implement business layer (service layer) along with repository layer. So my project has following layers EF <--- Repository <--- Service <--- Controller <--- View.

My context class looks like :

```
public class ToDoContext : DbContext
{
    public ToDoContext()
        : base("ToDoContext")
    {

    }

    public virtual DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet <Collaborator> Collaborators { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ActionTask> Tasks { get; set; }
}
```

My ProjectRepository looks like :

```
public class ProjectRepository : IProjectRepository, IDisposable
{
    ToDoContext Context;
    public ProjectRepository(ToDoContext context)
    {
        this.Context = context;
    }

    public virtual List<Project> AllProjects()
    {
        IQueryable<Project> projects = Context.Projects;
        return projects.ToList<Project>();
    }

    public Project Find(int? id)
    {
        // some code
    }

    public void InsertOrUpdate(Project project)
    {
        // some code
    }

    public void Delete(int? id)
    {
       // some code
    }

    public void Save()
    {

        // some code
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Context.Dispose();
    }
}
```

My ProjectService class looks like :

```
public class ProjectService : IProjectService
{
    IProjectRepository ProjectRepo;
    ICollaboratorRepository CollaboratorRepo;

    public ProjectService(IProjectRepository projectRepo, ICollaboratorRepository collaboratorRepo)
    {
        this.ProjectRepo = projectRepo;
        this.CollaboratorRepo = collaboratorRepo;
    }

    public List<Project> GetAllProjects()
    {
        return ProjectRepo.AllProjects();
    }

    public void CreateProject(FormCollection formData)
    {
        // code to parse form data as per my business needs

        // code to code to fetch related collaborator list

        // save the project data

    }

    public List<Collaborator> GetCollaborators(string[] collaboratorId)
    {
        // Fetch collaborator list using collaborator repository
        return CollaboratorRepository.GetAllCollaborators();
    }
}
```

Similarly I have implemented service and repository layer for my collaborator.

To summarize the code my **CreateProject()** method in ProjectService class fetches collaborator list using collaborator repository and create a new project attaching the collaborator list with this newly created project and save it.So i guess for me this whole process is **One Unit Of Work**.

When I fetch list of collaborators using CollaboratorRepository and try to save the newly created project using ProjectRepository, it throws me error "**An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.**". I guess this is because CollaboratorRepository dbcontext is not disposed yet. So I am manually disposing each context before using new context. I know I can't afford this overhead of manually disposing the context. Can anyone help me please?

I know I should be using same dbcontext object for one unit of work. But i don't know how to achieve this when dbcontext object is exposed to repository rather than service layer.

Comment: where do you init ToDoContext .. Are you using DI or what ?

Comment: Yeah I am using DI (Ninject).

Comment: Can you share it, how you are using it as i think problem will be in it

Comment: I do not have any configuration for DbContext in my NinjectWebCommon.cs file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is the IoC configured? You should register the LifeTime of the DbContext per Request\Thread, in order to get the same instance per *business transaction*.

*Tips*: In order to have a reusable Service outside of a web enviroment, do not pass the FormCollection to the CreateProject method. The parsing of the FormCollection should be done by the controller\model binder.

For **Ninject**, try [InRequestScope](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Common/wiki/InRequestScope)

```
kernel.Bind<ToDoContext>().To<ToDoContext>().InRequestScope();
```